# C struct definition standard

Tags: c++, c, struct, standards, standards-compliance

I'm programming in C in the last few years and I developed an habit to put the typedef of the struct in the header file, and to leave its definition in the source file, so others can use my files without letting them mess things up.

```
// header file
typedef struct s_example EXAMPLE
```

---

```
// source file
struct s_example {
       // something
};
```

is there something wrong it doing this, should i let others know what i do with my structs?

im just asking this because i see a lot of people showing everything in the header file.

Comment: If all they handle is a pointer, an incomplete type is fine.

Comment: Also note that in C++, the `typedef` is unneeded, since you don't have to use the `struct` keyword when you reference the bare type in the source like you do in C.

Comment: How is a user to be able to use a struct if they cannot see the format/fields?  and a struct should NOT be typedef'd..  Such typedef'ing just obscures the code and clutters the compiler name space.  Suggest: place the struct format in the header file (and perhaps an extern statement IF other programs need to access a local struct instance.)

Comment: @user3629249 I always `typedef` a `struct` so that the source code isn't cluttered with the word `struct` every time I declare one or use one as a function argument. Is that bad practice?

Comment: @WeatherVane: No, it's not bad practice. I don't know where user3629249 got that idea from. But I agree that it makes no sense to hide the layout of the structure from the programmers who are going to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The downside of only having the declaration in the header file is that all other source files that do not include the definition of the `struct` cannot instantiate an instance of that `struct`, but only a pointer to it. This is because, to those other source files, your `struct` is an [incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634495/c-typedef-incomplete-type). If that is fine for your application, then there is nothing wrong with just a declaration in the header.