# If struct type is defined in another .c file, it becomes incomplete type?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, incomplete-type

I can have no problem with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct foo
{
  void * data;
};

int main()
{
  printf("%ul\n", sizeof(struct foo));
}
```

but once, the struct is declared in another file and provided to compiler, the struct will magically becomes incomplete type:

EDIT (I have not provided all the code):

*b.h*:

```
struct foo
```

*b.c*:

```
#include "b.h"
struct foo
{
    void * data;
};
```

*a.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(struct foo));
}
```

triggered:
`$gcc a.c b.c`

still the same error:

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct foo’
  printf("%lu\n",sizeof(struct foo));
```

Comment: Not much magic here.  When compiling `a.c` how would the compiler know what `struct foo` is?  This is what header files are for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634495/c-typedef-incomplete-type - would this suffice?

Comment: @stark I am sorry I have not provided all the source, please revisit the quesiton once more, the error is still there

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the same for you

Comment: Declaring `struct foo;` (you are missing the semicolon) is called a forward declaration.  It says this type exists, but doesn't define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *translation unit*, i.e. **one** `.c` file and its `#include`d `.h` files must be self-standing, containing in required order all the *definitions* and *declarations* needed to compile the translation unit. Even if you provide several `.c` files on a GCC command line, **each** of these files is considered a **separate *translation unit***.

The *in order* means that the C source code of a translation unit can be compiled in *single pass*, meaning that the compiler could produce machine code at the same time as it parses the program, never having to keep in memory more than absolutely necessary, therefore all necessary declarations and definitions must appear in the source code *before* they are needed.

The C11/C18 standard says [(6.5.3.4p1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p1) that

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type *[...]*

And [(6.7.2.3p4)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.3p4)

> 4. All declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types that have the same scope and use the same tag declare the same type. Irrespective of whether there is a tag or what other declarations of the type are in the same translation unit, the type is incomplete*[129]* until immediately after the closing brace of the list defining the content, and complete thereafter.

With footnote *129* stating that

> *[129]* An incomplete type may only by used when the size of an object of that type is not needed. It is not needed, for example, when a `typedef` name is declared to be a specifier for a structure or union, or when a pointer to or a function returning a structure or union is being declared. (See incomplete types in 6.2.5.) The specification has to be complete before such a function is called or defined.

i.e. you translation unit `a.c` consists of the following code:

```
// code included from <stdio.h>
...
// code included from "b.h"
struct foo;

// rest of code in a.c
int main()
{
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(struct foo));
}
```

This is all knowledge that the *C* compiler has of `struct foo`, and by the time it hits the `sizeof(struct foo)`, by *6.7.2.3p4* the type `struct foo` is *still* incomplete and an error is produced.

As a fix, the `b.h` should, instead of the *completely useless and no-op `struct foo;`* have the actual structure definition:

`b.h`:

```
struct foo
{
    void * data;
};
```

Comment: Why to then use `static` for data, when different translation unit have their own unique data? And does that mean, I can have multiple structs with the same tag in different TU? becuase according to your answer, Structure must be defined *per* TU, which means I can have multiple struc with the same name in different TU

Comment: @milanHrabos yes, you can use the same struct tag for different structures in different TUs. If you want to use the same (compatible type) the definition they must use the *same* tag and have the *same* definition, however. As for static data, if not `static`, a file-scope variable will have *external* linkage and it can be seen in another translation unit. However the other translation unit needs to *declare* for the identifier to be seen (`extern int foo;`).

Answer (score 1):

When compiled with `$gcc a.c b.c`, `a.c` and `b.c` are still compiled separately. The object files with the machine code produced get clutched together by the linker thereafter.

When you use

```
printf("%lu\n",sizeof(struct foo));
```

`sizeof` can only be applied to an complete type as `sizeof` needs to know the exact size for a type to get the size of an object of that type in bytes.

But this is not fulfilled, since `struct foo` is only forward-declared inside of the included `b.h` file.

A forward-declaration of `struct foo` is permissible but `struct foo` is an incomplete type as long it wasn't declared really. This is having to do with separate TLUs in particular.

The declaration of `struct foo` within `b.c` to make `struct foo` a complete type  is not visible in `a.c` when the `sizeof` operator is applied to it; hence the error.

---

Possible Solution(s):

1. Swap the forward-declaration of `struct foo` with the declaration of `struct foo` inside of `b.h` and omit the declaration of ´`struct foo` in `b.c`.
2. `#include "b.c"` in `a.c` before applying the `sizeof` operator at the call to `printf()`.
3. Just declare `struct foo` in `a.c`. :-)

Comment: Why to then use `static` for data, when different translation unit have their own unique data? And does that mean, I can have multiple structs with the same tag in different TU? becuase according to your answer, Structure must be defined *per* TU, which means I can have multiple struc with the same name in different TU

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not make use of multiple source files. Each source file is independently compiled into object files.  At the compile stage, `a.c` and `b.c` are unknown to each other.  So `a.c` fails to compile down into an object as it depends on the knowledge of what `struct foo` is.

This is where a header file comes in.  It can be used to define common objects that will be shared by different source files, and then you include that header in each of the source files that need to make use of it.

Answer (score -1):

> If struct type is defined in another .c file, it becomes incomplete
> type?

It becomes an incomplete type if its definition is not seen in the current translation unit where its definition is required as for example using it in the operator `sizeof`.

In the translation unit that contains this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(struct foo));
}
```

`struct foo` is not defined.

So it is natural that the compiler will issue an error that there is used an incomplete type.

You should place the structure definition in a header if it is used more than one translation unit.

Or if you need to know only the size of the structure and it is not used anywhere else then you could just write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(struct foo { void * data; } ));
}
```

Pay attention that in the program above the type `struct foo` becomes defined in the block scope of main.

**EDIT:** After you updated your question then in this translation unit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(struct foo));
}
```

you have an incomplete structure declaration in the header `b.h` (where you forgot to place a semicolon after the declaration)

```
struct foo;
         ^^^
```

So in fact nothing was changed compared to the previous demonstrative program except that now the structure declaration has file scope instead of block scope as it takes place in the previous program. The compiler is unable to determine the size of the structure having no its definition

Pay attention to that in this command

```
$gcc a.c b.c
```

the files `a.c` and `b.c` are compiled separately.

Comment: what if struct is a bit more complex and files are compiled with another compile options?

Comment: @P__J__ There is all written clear in mu answer. Reread it one more if you have not understood it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have editted the question, please revisit it