# Why is this struct unknown at compile time?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, definition

I am using `Ox`, `bison` and `lex` to write an attribute grammar. In my grammar, I use a symbol table to keep track of identifiers that are in scope.

The symbol table struct is defined in a `parser.h` header:

```c
struct st_;
typedef struct st_
{
    char** names;
    void** vals;
    char** types;
    int len;
    int maxlen;
} ST;
```

Ox produces the files `oxout.tab.h` and `oxout.tab.c` which are the outputs of `bison` after checking the grammar.

This is the head part of my `ox` file:

```c
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.h"

int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
extern int line_number;

struct test {
    ST s;
};

ST add(ST table, char* name, void* val, char* type);
ST addMaybe(ST table, char* name, void* val, char* type);
ST addAll(ST old, ST new);
ST init_st();
bool containsT(ST table, char* name, char* type);
bool contains(ST table, char* name);

void oxerrorf(char* f, char* s);
%}

%start Start

%token INTERFACE END CLASS IMPLEMENTS VAR METHOD INT RETURN IF THEN ELSE
%token WHILE DO NOT AND NEW THIS _NULL EOC SCOL COL BRACL BRACR DOT COMMA 
%token ASSIGNMENT PLUS ASTERISK MINUS LT EQ DEC HEX ID NEWLINE

@attributes { ST st; } Program Interface Class MaybeIDs InterfaceContents
@attributes { ST st; } Types Members Stats Negations Term Exprs Expr
@attributes { ST st; } Additions Ands ArithOps MaybeElse
@attributes { char* yystrval; } ID
@attributes { ST st; char* name; } AbstractMethod Type Member Par Stat
@attributes { ST st; ST stUp; } Pars 


@traversal @preorder LRpre
@traversal PV

%%
// definitions...
```

this is transformed to the following `oxout.tab.c`:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#if defined(__sun) && defined(__SVR4)
#include <strings.h>
#else
#include <string.h>
#endif

/* Identify Ox output. */
#define YYYOX 1

#line 1 "littleparser.y"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.h"

int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
extern int line_number;

struct test {
    ST s;
};

ST add(ST table, char* name, void* val, char* type);
ST addMaybe(ST table, char* name, void* val, char* type);
ST addAll(ST old, ST new);
ST init_st();
bool containsT(ST table, char* name, char* type);
bool contains(ST table, char* name);

void oxerrorf(char* f, char* s);
#line 93 "oxout.y"

struct yyyT1
#line 42 "littleparser.y"
 { ST st; }
#line 98 "oxout.y"
;

struct yyyT2
#line 43 "littleparser.y"
 { ST st; }
#line 104 "oxout.y"
;

struct yyyT3
#line 44 "littleparser.y"
 { ST st; }
#line 110 "oxout.y"
;

struct yyyT4
#line 45 "littleparser.y"
 { char* yystrval; }
#line 116 "oxout.y"
;

struct yyyT5
#line 46 "littleparser.y"
 { ST st; char* name; }
#line 122 "oxout.y"
;

struct yyyT6
#line 47 "littleparser.y"
 { ST st; ST stUp; }
#line 128 "oxout.y"
;
```

Now when I compile this using

```sh
> gcc  parser.h oxout.tab.h lex.yy.c oxout.tab.c -o ag
```

`gcc` throws me the most curious error:

```sh
littleparser.y:42:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
   42 | @attributes { ST st; } Program Interface Class MaybeIDs InterfaceContents
      |    ^~
littleparser.y:43:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
   43 | @attributes { ST st; } Types Members Stats Negations Term Exprs Expr
      |    ^~
littleparser.y:44:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
   44 | @attributes { ST st; } Additions Ands ArithOps MaybeElse
      |    ^~
littleparser.y:46:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
   46 | @attributes { ST st; char* name; } AbstractMethod Type Member Par Stat
      |    ^~
littleparser.y:47:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
   47 | @attributes { ST st; ST stUp; } Pars
      |    ^~
littleparser.y:47:11: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
   47 | @attributes { ST st; ST stUp; } Pars
      |           ^~
```

The interesting this is this:

```c
struct test {
    ST s;
};

ST add(ST table, char* name, void* val, char* type);
// and the other declarations
```

seem to compile fine;

however

```c
struct yyyT1
#line 42 "littleparser.y"
 { ST st; }
#line 98 "oxout.y"
;
```

throws the unknown type name error.

Why is that?
All these definitions seem to be in scope/defined at the time it is compiled. (Also when I look at the output of the preprocessor the contents of `parser.h` are inlined before their first usage.)

I am not extremely savvy with `C` so I have probably missed something quite obvious I guess.
Sadly [C Typedef - Incomplete Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634495/c-typedef-incomplete-type) did not help me finding the error;

I tried to define the struct inside the `c` file, move the `typedef` somewhere else, keeping it all in the `h` file, but nothing seems to work.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: It's wrong (although should be harmless) to have the header files on the command line: `gcc lex.yy.c oxout.tab.c -o ag` should be right. It looks from the error messages that you're compiling the .y file with gcc because the error messages refer to @attributes although that may be a function of the #line directives. Try compiling each of the .c files in turn, and if you're still stuck, remove all the #line directives to see if you can get a better error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paul Hankin suggested, this wasn't an error coming from the file `littleparser.y`.

After removing all `#line .*` definitions in all the generated c files and compiling it again, the following output

```sh
lex.yy.c:574:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
  574 |  { ST st; }
      |    ^~
lex.yy.c:580:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
  580 |  { ST st; }
      |    ^~
lex.yy.c:586:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
  586 |  { ST st; }
      |    ^~
lex.yy.c:598:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
  598 |  { ST st; char* name; }
      |    ^~
lex.yy.c:604:4: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
  604 |  { ST st; ST stUp; }
      |    ^~
lex.yy.c:604:11: error: unknown type name ‘ST’
  604 |  { ST st; ST stUp; }
      |           ^~
```

suggested that the problem was linked to the `lexer.y` instead of the `litteparser.y`.
After adding `#include "parser.h"` in `lexer.y` and recompiling it, everything worked fine.